# Product of Array Except Self with tail recursion

Tags: scala

I would like to know if below function can be rewritten using tail recursion and using recursion in this case is any helpful in terms of time/space complexity?, below is what i have tried without tail recursion

```
input:[4,2,4,6]
output:[48,96,48,32]

  def productExceptSelf(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int]={
    val len = nums.length

    val output_arr= new Array[Int](len)

    output_arr(0)=1
    for(i<- 1 to len-1)
    {
      output_arr(i) = nums(i-1) * output_arr(i-1)
    }

    var R =1
    var j=len-1
    while(j>=0)
    {
      output_arr(j) =  output_arr(j)* R
      R = R * nums(j)
      j-=1
    }

    output_arr
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how would you expect to write this using tail-recursion, but the simplest way would be something like this:
*PS: I am using **ArraySeq** which is an immutable array (that was introduced on `2.13`), feel free to keep using normal arrays*.

```
def productExceptSelf(nums: ArraySeq[Int]): ArraySeq[Int] = {
  val totalProduct = nums.product

  nums.map(x => totalProduct / x)
}
```

---

Solution without using division.

```
def productExceptSelf(nums: ArraySew[Int]) : ArraySeq[Int] =
  ArraySeq.tabulate(nums.length) { i =>
    nums.foldLeft(1 -> 0) { case ((acc, j), x) =>
      val newAcc = if (i == j) acc else acc * x
      newAcc -> (j + 1)
    }._1
  }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention solution should be without using division, this is one of the problem im trying to solve from Leetcode

Answer (score 2):

Solution without using division.

```
def productExceptSelf(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] =
  Array.fill(nums.length)(nums)
       .zipWithIndex
       .map{case (ns,x) => ns.patch(x,Seq(),1).product}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It keeps track of the index and multiplies if the index of the current element isn't the same. However, it's not very idiomatic.

```
def productExceptSelf(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] =
  productExceptSelf(nums, Array.fill(nums.size)(1), 0).toArray

def productExceptSelf(orig: Array[Int], res: Array[Int], i: Int): Array[Int] =
  if (i == orig.size) res
  else productExceptSelf(
    orig, 
    res.zipWithIndex.map { 
      case (n, j) => if (j == i) n else n * orig(i)
    }, 
    i + 1
  )
```

I like this one better:

```
def productExceptSelf(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] =
  nums.indices.map {
    i => nums.slice(0, i).product * nums.slice(i + 1, nums.size).product
  }.toArray
```

You might prefer a view to do it lazily

```
def productExceptSelf(nums: Array[Int]) =
  nums.indices.map {
    i => nums.view.slice(0, i).product * nums.view.slice(i + 1, nums.size).product
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Starting from the right and recursing left, compute the right side product
# and pass it down. Upon reaching the left, compute the left side product,
# update the array, and bubble that value up. 

def prod_not_self(arr, i, right):
    if (i == 0):
        left = 1
    else:
        left = arr[i-1] * prod_not_self(arr, i - 1, right * arr[i])

    arr[i] = right * left

    return left


if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    print(arr)
    prod_not_self(arr, len(arr) - 1, 1)
    print(arr)
    print()

    arr = [-1, 1, 0, -3, 3]
    print(arr)
    prod_not_self(arr, len(arr) - 1, 1)
    print(arr)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).